# Have one column equal to [auto-increment] primary key when adding in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to have a column have the same value as the primary key when a record is added - and rather than having to update the record right after it has been added, is there a better way to do this?

What I'm currently doing:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO 'mytable' SET ...");
$db->query("UPDATE 'mytable' SET someColumn=".$db->insert_id." WHERE id=".$db->insert_id);
```

What I want to do is just run one query instead of two for this, if that is possible.

Is what I'm currently doing wrong? Not exactly, I just want to do this because it's always good to learn new methods for coding. :)

Comment: Can you explain why you want data to be duplicated?  You already have the data in your database and I don't understand why you want it twice.

Comment: I can't think of any reason you would use this where it wouldn't lead to problems.

Comment: I'm using it (the duplicate column) for data ordering purposes after the entry has been made.  IF you know of a better way with little hassle, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Can't you order by the original column?

Comment: You haven't been clear in what exactly you're trying to do so I have no way of suggesting a better way of accomplishing your end goal.  All you've told us so far is it's for "data ordering purposes".

Comment: Well, I want all entries to initially order by their order of entry, but still be able to "swap" the order of entries.  From the snippet I have listed, someColumn is used only for ordering entries.

Answer (score 2):

If `someColumn` is *always* going to be equal to `id`, it's a useless denormalization. One should simply use `id` instead of `someColumn` in queries.

In a proper RDBMS or if you were generating primary keys on the application side, you could use the key generator to populate both the `id` and `someColumn` columns with the same value. I don't know if MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT hack provides anything resembling thread-safe SQL sequences, though. In any case, you should probably read the specific [documentation pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) as no amount of standard knowledge or experience will help you with the AUTO_INCREMENT <strike>brainf</strike> quirk.

Alternatively, you could have a special value for `someColumn` (or a boolean column) which would mean "just inserted / use `id`'s value".

Comment: Key generator doesn't sound too bad, I'll keep that one in mind.  Thank you.

Comment: Also looks like I can use "someColumn=LAST_INSERT_ID()+1" in my query, which shouldn't be horrible.  Anyone have objections to using this?

Comment: It wouldn't be synchronized. Simply two concurrent inserts would break it.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO ... SET? That's wrong. <-- **No, it's not wrong, i was fool.**

I would create CASCADE foreing key constraint if it is possible.

Comment: I saw `INSERT INTO ... SET` last week or so for the first time myself.  It appears to be completely valid.

Comment: Yeah, i see that now  but still it is strange to me. :)

Comment: I may try this, although it does seem somewhat messy if it's even possible.  In the meantime I'm skimming through MySQL docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need it sequential and not necessarily *exactly* the same as the id column, you could do:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET foo = (select max(foo) + 1 from mytable)
```

As an aside, this looks dangerous to me:

```
$db->query("UPDATE 'mytable' SET someColumn=".$db->insert_id." WHERE id=".$db->insert_id);
```

Assuming you're using pdo, always use prepared statements/bound parameters to bind values to queries - never interpolate strings. E.g.;

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE 'mytable' SET someColumn = :someColumn WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(":someColumn" => $db->insert_id, ":id" => $db->insert_id));
```